# Can I automatically implement classes?

Tags: haskell, scalaz

In Scalaz every `Monad` instance is automatically an instance of `Applicative`.

```
implicit val listInstance = new Monad[List] {
  def point[A](a: => A) = List(a)
  def bind[A, B](fa: List[A])(f: A => List[B]) = fa flatMap f
}

List(2) <*> List((x: Int) => x + 1) // Works!
```

Another example: `Arrow` is automatically a `Profunctor`.

However, in Haskell I must provide an instance of `Applicative` for every `Monad` again and again.

Is it possible to avoid this repetitive job?

Comment: Not at the moment, AFAIK. You have to add `instance Applicative M where pure=return; (<*>)=ap`. I believe I saw some discussion about autoderiving superclasses, i.e. implement `Monad` and `Functor` and have `Applicative` implicitly added, but it has not been implemented (again, AFAIK). Perhaps you can write some Template Haskell to scan the current monad instances and autogenerate applicatives. I'm not sure this is possible, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't currently possible, though it would be if you changed the existing library to support this. Turning DefaultSignatures on would let you write

```
class Applicative f where
    pure :: a -> f a
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

    default pure :: Monad f => a -> f a
    default (<*>) :: Monad f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap
```

Then once you had implemented `instance Monad M where {- ... -}`, a simple `instance Applicative M` (with no `where` or method definitions) would inherit these default implementations. I'm not sure why this wasn't done.

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes when there are two places from which to derive the `Applicative` instance. For instance, suppose `m` is the type `a b` where `Arrow a`. Then there's an obvious instance of `Applicative` from this definition as well. Which one should the compiler use? It should work out the same, of course, but Haskell has no way to check this. By making us write out the instances, Haskell at least forces us to think about the consistency of our definitions.

If you want, there's the `WrappedMonad` class in `Control.Applicative`, which provides all the obvious instances with a `newtype` wrapper, but using `WrapMonad` and `unwrapMonad` all the time isn't that attractive either.